# Java - MouseWheelEvent triggers twice

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am working on a swing JFrame, and one of the features of the program involved scaling an image in the window using the mouse's scroll wheel. I have implemented a MouseAdapter which is added as a MouseWheelListener for the JFrame itself.

```
/**
 * Handles scroll wheel activity.
 */
private MouseAdapter wheelListener = new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        int notches = e.getWheelRotation();
        System.out.println(notches);
        while (notches > 0) {
            controller.zoomIn();
            notches--;
        }
        while (notches < 0) {
            controller.zoomOut();
            notches++;
        }
    }
};
```

And in the JFrame constructor:

```
public MainFrame() {
    ...
    addMouseWheelListener(wheelListener);
    ...
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the event triggers twice for each "click" when rolling the scroll wheel. I was unable to find anyone with a similar problem.

I tried putting `if(e.getScrollType() == MouseWheelEvent.WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL) { ... }` in the `mouseWheelMoved` method to see if there were two different types of events happening, but they're both `WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL's`.

I also tried printing out the event's source to see if it was coming from different windows/panes, but again they're both from my main JFrame window.

Does anyone know, or can spot, why I'm getting two events when I should be getting one?

EDIT: put the wrong line in the add wheel listener section, sorry.
EDIT: After some testing, I was able to use `.hashCode()` to verify that there are two unique `MouseWheelEvents`. I suspect the MouseAdapter is getting added twice somehow. I add it in the MainFrame's constructor and verified that it only happens once there.

Comment: When I tried your code in my [sscce](http://sscce.org), it worked fine. Are you adding the listener more than once? Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: Also, why show us the `addWindowListener(...)` bit when your question has nothing to do with WindowListeners?

Comment: `" I suspect the MouseAdapter is getting added twice somehow."`: as I suspected. You're not showing the offending code either.

Comment: If I knew where the offending code was, I would be able to fix it, right? Is there a way to have a listener recognize when it is added? If so I could throw an exception to trace it...

Comment: It has to be in your code, and all you need to do is search your code for where you add these types of listeners.

Comment: All the hashCode tells you is that you are indeed receiving two unique events, not the same one twice. It says nothing about the event source.  What is your mouse configuration (lines per notch) set to?

Comment: Correct, two separate events. I checked my mouse's scroll speed, and also tried the touch pad. No matter my settings, I always get two events. When I double the line that adds the listener, I get 4 runs through the event handler, but only 2 unique events.

Comment: I'm going to guess it's some issue with my particular system. I tried copying the listener and the add listener line to a separate set of code and still get 2 unique events for each wheel movement. It happens both for the wireless mouse and the touch pad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an e.consume() solve this issue.

```
private MouseAdapter wheelListener = new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        e.consume() // avoid the event to be triggred twice
        int notches = e.getWheelRotation();
        System.out.println(notches);
        while (notches > 0) {
            controller.zoomIn();
            notches--;
        }
        while (notches < 0) {
            controller.zoomOut();
            notches++;
        }
    }
};
```